# Get Neo4j version from dump

Tags: neo4j

I have a Neo4j database dump created with a particular version of Neo4j. I am trying to restore the database but I am getting an error (show below) that I suspect is because the dump was created with a version different from my current neo4j version. Is there a way to get the version with which the dump was created using the dump itself ?

**Error when loading database dump from debug.log**

```
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.UnderlyingStorageException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/neostore (Permission denied)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.verifyRecordFormat(NeoStores.java:217)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.<init>(NeoStores.java:144)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.openNeoStores(StoreFactory.java:129)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.openAllNeoStores(StoreFactory.java:93)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine.<init>(RecordStorageEngine.java:187)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.buildStorageEngine(NeoStoreDataSource.java:514)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:367)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:116)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:225)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:146)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.CommunityGraphFactory.newGraphDatabase(CommunityGraphFactory.java:41)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:90)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:180)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:124)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:91)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:32)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/neostore (Permission denied)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:347)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:261)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:216)
    at org.neo4j.io.fs.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.open(DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.java:65)
    at org.neo4j.io.fs.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.open(DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.java:50)
    at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.SingleFilePageSwapper.<init>(SingleFilePageSwapper.java:170)
    at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.SingleFilePageSwapperFactory.createPageSwapper(SingleFilePageSwapperFactory.java:66)
    at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPagedFile.<init>(MuninnPagedFile.java:149)
    at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCache.map(MuninnPageCache.java:412)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.MetaDataStore.getRecord(MetaDataStore.java:285)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.verifyRecordFormat(NeoStores.java:198
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an issue with file permissions:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/neostore (Permission denied)
```

Check that the `/var/lib/neo4j/` directory and all files inside (recursively) are accessible to the user you run Neo4j database under (typically `neo4j`).

This situation usually happens when you copy the data under different user or root. You can fix this by running:

```
chown -R neo4j:neo4j /var/lib/neo4j/
```